# why do i get the error "The system cannot find the file specified?"

Tags: java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class FileRead
{


public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
{   

    try
    {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("data.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

        String strLine;     
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {

          System.out.println (strLine);
        }   
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }

}
```

I put the data.txt in the same location as the java project. I have to get this done for a research project for my java class.

Answer (score 0):

Use `src/data.txt` to find a file in the same place as your project :)

Means that it is the same location as your source folder (put it inside src)

Comment: I still get the same error, am i putting the file in the wrong place?

Comment: Put it in your src folder?

Comment: @NoahDavison and use src/data.txt

Answer (score 0):

you forgot `./` thats why it says not found file